# take stdin from file to control background java process

Tags: java, bash, stdin, minecraft

I would like to run a Minecraft server in the background with Ubuntu, but every time I do it stops running.I am also running bash as my shell.

```
java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.jar nogui &
```

When I run jobs I get this at first.

```
[1]+  Running   java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.jar nogui &
```

Then this a few seconds later.

```
[1]+  Stopped    java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.jar nogui
```

Later I found out that it will stay "Running" if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to some files.

```
java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.jar nogui > out.txt 2> err.txt < in.txt &
```

It works great, but I want to use the in.txt file as input for the running java process. When I first run this it executes the in.txt once. So if I have /stop in in.txt it will stop the server. But ONLY once. I would like to put commands in the text file and have that passed to the minecraft server. The file would become my keyboard input while the process is running. I know I can use screen, but I want to see if I can run it with a file as input. Again the in.txt would be my input. 
So I could do something like this.

```
echo -e "/stop\r" > in.txt
```

OR

```
echo -e "/time set 0\r" > in.txt
```

**Another rabbit hole.**


I even tried making my own pipe. This makes minecraft run in the background.

```
 mkfifo pipe; 
 java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.jar nogui &> out.txt < pipe &;
 cat > pipe
```

If I `cat > pipe` my prompt is taken again, but I can enter commands and it executes them as stdin. So if I do `/say hi` it will run it. Awesome! One problem. I need my bash prompt back. If I close it by using `Ctrl-C`, I'll lose my stdin forever! I can keep it around by `Ctrl-Z`. Later If I need it I'll `fg`. But that is very crude. I would like to run a script that would stick something into that at a later time. Something like `echo "/say hi" > pipe`. I lose stdin if I don't keep something running. `echo` runs once. That's the problem, it collapses stdin.
  I am a novice at bash scripting so a little help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really getting what you're asking. It seems you are able to 'take stdin from a file'. Are you saying you want to be able to edit the file while Minecraft is running? Is there a Minecraft CLI? Would it work if you just didn't run it background; i.e., remove the '&'?

Comment: @zanerock Yes it works, but it only works when you first execute the java jar. After that it doesn't look at the file anymore. I want that in.txt file as my keyboard. For example if I put a `/stop` in the in.txt the server will start and then shutdown. If it's blank and later I put something in it, it won't use that as input. It does nothing. I need the `&` so I can continue using my bash shell. Even  if I don't use the `&` it still does the same thing. Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got the idea of using a FIFO. You need to run it with the following command:

```bash
while true; do cat pipe ; done | java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.jar nogui > out.txt &
```

The while loop will make sure that even if the process you use for writing to the FIFO closes the file, the JVM standard input will not be closed. It will just start catenating `pipe` to it again and the while`s standard output is considered one long stream.

Comment: Thank you so much! If I add `exec 3<>pipe` to the last script block I have, it has the same outcome you have up above. I can `echo` stuff to pipe file and it works. I'm wondering what that does? I know this is above and beyond but if I close out my shell it stops any background processes. How can I run this as a separate process so I can close out my shell? The ends result would be to `echo` stuff the the pipe file and manage Minecraft from there. Then later I'll kill the process if I need to after I `/stop` the MC server. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I suppose you should put your command, pipe redirection and all, in a shell script if you haven't done so already, and run that shell script using `nohup script.sh &`.